# How to export product csv with full url of product

Tags: magento, csv, export

I want to export a product CSV with full product url i.e including base url (I don't want to do it manually).

Is it possible to customize the code so that the product export has the full url?

Comment: First result on Google -> http://t3jsot.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/magento-export-products-with-full-urls.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

// Load the Magento core

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);

// Load the product collection

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //Select everything from the table
 ->addUrlRewrite(); //Generate nice URLs

/*
 For this example I am generating a CSV file,
 but you can change this to suit your needs.
*/

echo "title,sku,id,url\n" ."<br>";

foreach($collection as $product) {
 //Load the product categories
 $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
 //Select the last category in the list
 $categoryId = end($categories);
 //Load that category
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

 echo '"'.$product->getTitle().'","'.
  $product->getSku().'",'.
  $product->getId().',"'.
  //This will the proper URL, the base url is optional, though make sure you remove the trailing export.php (or whatever you name this file)
  str_replace('export.php/','',Mage::getBaseUrl()).$product->getUrlPath($category).'"'.
  "\n" ."<br>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Create export.csv on root ..write a code to export csv the new thing is that you have to hardcode base url in the path of the product..

for example ..existing path category/product/

base url/category/product/

But remember to keep the code correct..
```