# How to configure Magmi and export product

Tags: magento

How can i configure MAGMI Application and How can i used for Export and also Import. What is the procedure to connect my server.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0cDY.png)

Comment: Magmi can be used for import purpose only

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity : i get more information from here, may this is use full to others.

Comment: @JeevaRathinam - Maybe, but it does need to be programming-related on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Magmi is only for import.

**Removing upgrade/upload functions are disable for security reasons:**
 Follow the link: https://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/git/ci/875893212a9c0a89d018466d023bd2fbd339dbb0/

**Import steps:**

1. **Configure Global parameters Section:**

   - **Database** (enter here the connection info to magento DB)

     - *host* : enter Mysql host name for magento DB (defaults to localhost)
     - *port* : enter Mysql port for magento DB (defaults to mysql base port : 3306)
     - *DB Name* : name of magento database
     - *Username* : name of user to access magento database
     - *Password* : password of user to access magento database
     - *Table Prefix* : if you chose to use a table prefix for your magento table (at the time of magento installation) then put the prefix here also(without the trailing _)
     - **Note:** Check your local.xml for db host name, db password, db username.
   - **Magento** (for magento filesystem location info & version)

     - *version*: select version of your magento (You are using 1.9)
     - Give path to magmi installed in magento dir. (Your magmi is in magento root directory- leave it blank)
   - **Global** (here magmi common general setup)

     - *Directory permissions*: 755
     - *File permissions*: 644

Then save global permission.

2. **Configure Current Profile Section:**

   - *CSV base directory*: Magento import directory (i.e. var/import). Also paste your .csv file to that folder.
   - *File to import*: Select CSV file to run for import.
     Then Save Profile (Default).
3. **Run Magmi**:

   - Run Magmi with profile: Default
   - Select using mode according to your requirement.
   - Run Import
4. For more :

   - [Magmi Wiki](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
   - [Cateogry create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740347/cateogry-create-via-magmi-with-no-product)

**Image Ref:** [image]

Comment: may i know the export data which is used to import

Comment: Use magento default export. If you want .csv format then check the links: 
http://itheadaches.com/import-sample-magento-magmi-configurable-product-csv/

Comment: @ Shahed Jamal : Actually i have export

Comment: @ Shahed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581050/how-can-i-solve-product-export-error

Comment: This what am going to using magmi

Comment: Do you have ever faced no valid data send error while export product

Comment: No. Use dataflow - profiles to export & import. Increase php execution time.

Comment: system - import/export - dataflow profiles - export all products,   when i try this i get error like,

Comment: what is the meaning of 500 internal server error while export products.

Comment: See this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67869/trying-to-export-products-give-500-internal-server-error

Increase local value of execution time and try.

Comment: how can i use manual script export.php, when i try to run in browser, the value disply on my browser, not exported as a excel file,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869118/how-to-export-product-csv-with-full-url-of-product

Comment: Using this you can download the csv. But if you have large number of products then increase the php execuation time. Or add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` at the strting of the script.
Link of the script:
https://github.com/shahed-jamal/Magento-export-product-csv-programmatically.git

Comment: Removing upgrade/upload functions are disable for security reasons: Follow the link: https://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/git/ci/875893212a9c0a89d018466d023bd2fbd339dbb0/

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ccc.magentoadmin_user' doesn't exist' in /home/ccc/public_html/magmi/inc/dbhelper.class.php:222/home/ccc/public_html/magmi/web/magmi_chooseprofile.php(2): require_once('/home/ccc/p...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/ccc/public_html/magmi/inc/dbhelper.class.php on line 222

Comment: help @  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587126/how-can-i-solve-magmi-error-after-db-connect