# How can i solve product export error

Tags: export, magento-1.9

I have try to export my all products, but only minimum of products only exported, whole product not exported, which means 100's of products successfully imported, and my whole products not exported, in my store 30,000 products,

i have tried both export :

Errors :
system - import/export - export error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5y2X.png

system - import/export - dataflow profiles - export all products error:  (500 internal server error)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOCHu.png

Comment: And this is my phpinfo :

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kh99CY6.png

Comment: What is the meaning of - no valid data send error -

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?